# Не работает кнопка на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, dle

Не работает кнопка помогите, код:

```html
<div class="show-full" title="Смотреть" href="{full-link}">
  <div>
    <span class="fas fa-play"></span>
  </div>
  Смотреть
</div>
```

Кнопка после нажатия должна перекидать на страницу с плеером, но она не кликабельная.
Класс `<div class="show-full"` стилизован в css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В обработчике записано так:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.show-trailer', function(){
    var url = $(this).siblings('.show-full').attr("data-href");
    $.fancybox.open($('#trailer_load'), {});
    $("#trailer_load").find('.tr_load-wrp').load(url + " #trailer_place > *");
```

Comment: Что из этого кнопка? Почему и как она должна работать?

Comment: Потому что div не кнопка. Что бы что то происходило по нажатию, надо написать функию обработчик, либо заменить div на тег a

Answer (score 0):

В Вашем коде находится только div. А это, как Вам должно быть известно, что это элемент разделения контента HTML (). Является универсальным контейнером для потокового контента. Он не влияет на контент или макет до тех пор, пока не будет стилизован с помощью CSS. А Вам, как я понял нужна кнопка, а это **button**. Вот пример, остальные способы смотрите в интернете/ютубе:

```html
<form action="page/new.html" target="_blank">
   <button>Переход по ссылке</button>
  </form>
```